# How to adjust the height of a container as the maximum height of its sibling in a row

Tags: flutter

I have two widgets in a row. The first widget is a black line with width 5.0, the second widget is a text widget whose size may vary according to the content. I want the first container to have the same height as of the second widget

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to make both widget child of an IntrinsicHeight widget and then declare the height of the first container as double.infinity. This should solve your problem. Example code is given below:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(  //this is the first container
         height: double.infinity
      ),
      secondWidget(
      )
    ],
)
```

Let me know if you have further query. Happy coding!

Comment: Solved the problem.

Comment: This `IntrinsicHeight` also works for `Stack`.

Answer (score 1):

There's some valuable information missing from the accepted answer.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, <-- IMPORTANT
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(), <-- NO NEED FOR HEIGHT, ANY WIDGET SUPPORTED NOW
      SecondWidget(),
    ],
)
```

This way you can make any widget as tall as `SecondWidget`, not just a `Container`.

Comment: The crossAxisAlignment property goes inside the Row widget rather than the IntrinsicHeight Widget.

Comment: @KanishkaMunshi, thanks. I just update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expanded` widget. It divides siblings to the same height or width.
here is the code:

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
   )
```

And here is the result:

[image]

That is so easy. I wish it could help.

Comment: It will adjust the with also. I just needed the height of as the maximum height of that Row. Anyway thank you.

Comment: You can use Column instead of Row.

Comment: How align elements horizontally in a column? We use Row for that.

Comment: So do I. Actually you need a combination of Rows and Columns.

Comment: The answer by @Md Golam Rahman Tushar was the one I was looking for. If you find a better way to do it, please edit the answer with the new solution.